# Selecting many XML nodes into List<T>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need some help selecting all of the `<encoding>` nodes and adding them to a `List<Core.Encoding>`. I get values for height and width but when I un-comment VideoCodec, AudioCodec, and ContainerType I get the error

> an Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
<media>
  <id>123456</id>
  <media_type>Video</media_type>
  <encodings>
    <encoding>
      <height>270</height>
      <width>404</width>
      <video_codec>H264</video_codec>
      <audio_codec>Aac</audio_codec>
      <container_type>Mp4</container_type>
    </encoding>
    <encoding>
      <height>270</height>
      <width>404</width>
      <video_codec>H264</video_codec>
      <audio_codec>Aac</audio_codec>
      <container_type>Mp4</container_type>
    </encoding>
  </encodings>
</media>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
[Serializable]
public class Encoding
{
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string VideoCodec { get; set; }
    public string AudioCodec { get; set; }
    public string ContainerType { get; set; }
}

private List<Core.Encoding> SomeMethod(string authenticatedURL)
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(authenticatedURL);

    list.AddRange((from encoding in xml.DescendantsAndSelf("encoding")
                   select new Core.Encoding
                   {
                       Height = encoding.Element("height").Value,
                       Width = encoding.Element("width").Value,
                       VideoCodec = encoding.Element("video_codec").Value,
                       AudioCodec = encoding.Element("audio_codec").Value,
                       ContainerType = encoding.Element("container_type").Value
                   }));
}
```

Comment: @T.S. Are you sure about that? It seems that you are unaware that a constructor may be followed by an object initializer `{}`, and if it is, `()` becomes optional. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer#example

Comment: @spender ooops. you're right. See, we no longer do this much. Because any error during atomic initialization is hard to debug. If you don't use it, you lose it. I now even remember that editor grays parenthesis out because they are not necessary

Comment: Object reference not set could be anything - `list`, `authenticateUrl`..

Comment: Ok, I see. I missed the point that you may comment the element. I updated my answer to fix the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that you get the exception when you *comment out* those elements, because they're not part of the document.  You only show the document in a state where it doesn't throw the exception.

Commented (out), exception thrown:

```
<!--<video_codec>H264</video_codec>-->
```

Uncommented, no exception:

```
<video_codec>H264</video_codec>
```

You need to check for `null` on all those `Element` calls.  A null-propagating access (`?.`) of the `Value` property is a simple way to do that:

```
VideoCodec = encoding.Element("video_codec")?.Value
```

Comment: My thought exactly!

Answer (score 0):

This works (tested)(**updated**) And I used both, c#5 and c#7 syntax

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
// . . . . .  . .

// test data
var s = @"<media>
<id>123456</id>
<media_type>Video</media_type>
<encodings>
  <encoding>
    <height>270</height>
    <width>404</width>
    <video_codec>H264</video_codec>
    <audio_codec>Aac</audio_codec>
    <container_type>Mp4</container_type>
  </encoding>
  <encoding>
    <height>270</height>
    <width>404</width>
    <video_codec>H264</video_codec>
  <!--  <audio_codec>Aac</audio_codec> -->
    <container_type>Mp4</container_type>
  </encoding>
</encodings>
</media>";

var root = XElement.Parse(s);

// Linq to XML (select) 
var coll = root.Element("encodings").Elements("encoding").Select(e => new Encoding()
{
    Height = e.Element("height").Value,
    Width = e.Element("height").Value,
    // c#5
    VideoCodec = (e.Elements("video_codec").Any() ? e.Element("video_codec").Value : string.Empty),
    AudioCodec = (e.Elements("audio_codec").Any() ? e.Element("audio_codec").Value : string.Empty), 
    //  c#6
    ContainerType = e.Element("container_type")?.Value 
});

// test
coll.ToList().ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.VideoCodec));
```

If you have many `<media>` tags, use `SelectMany`.

`coll.ToList()` will make your list